# How did Valkris obtain information on Project Genesis?

Tags: star-trek

At the beginning of *Star Trek III*, we see Valkris meeting with Kruge and delivering plans for Project Genesis.  Where/how did Valkris get this info?

Comment: Many Bothans died...

Answer (score 3):

Valkris was on a ship with humans and stated that she had purchased the Genesis data.  One of the humans was expecting to be paid, so presumably that human acquired the information in some underhanded fashion.  Spies within Starfleet, hacked computer systems... take your pick.  Once the Federation made Genesis "planet forbidden", the moles found within any large bureaucracy would have immediately started digging.